# Run script on particular day without crontab

Tags: unix

I am having a driving script which calls internally multiple scripts.

```
`sh main_script.sh > main_script.log`
```

inside main_script.sh

```
sh -x script_1.sh
sh -x script_2.sh
sh -x script_3.sh
```

I Have to run the internal scripts in particular dates and manage failure scenarios accordingly, If any of the script fails then while retrying it should run only that particular sub script.

```
script_1.sh - 25th of every month
script_2.sh - daily 
script_3.sh - Every quarterly month end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
current_day=$(date +%e)
current_time=$(date +"%H:%M")
current_month=$(date +"%m")

## Execute script_1.sh on 25th every month and at time = 10 AM
if [ $current_day == 25 ] && [ $current_time == '10:00' ]
then
   n=0
   until [ $n -ge 5 ]
   do
      sh -x script_1.sh && break  
      n=$[$n+1]
      sleep 15
 done
 fi
 ##This will keep retrying in every 15 seconds for 5 times and break out of loop if the command got successful    


## Execute script_2.sh daily at time = 10 AM
if [ $current_time == '10:00' ]
then
   sh -x script_2.sh
fi

## Execute script_3.sh for every quarter month-end(run for months Apr,Aug,Dec on 30th at 10 AM)

if [ $current_month == 4 ] || [ $current_month == 8 ] || [ $current_month == 12 ]
then 
  if [ $current_day == 30 ] && [ $current_time == '10:00' ]
    then
      sh -x script_3.sh
  fi
fi
```

Replace `main_script.sh` with above code. And keep executing `main_script.sh` all the time.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to have retry mechanism if there is a failure on any script.For eg script_1.sh failed then if i rerun it should run script_1.sh only

Comment: @user2672739 Retry logic here can be implemented, but it would be quite intricate. Probably, using a scheduler like `Airflow` which is quite feature rich in terms of having retry abilities with re-running just the sub-script present. Achieving this through shell script does not sound a very good idea to me.

Comment: I think this can be achieved in shell script. Can you help how its possible

Comment: I've updated retry in my code for `script_1.sh`. You can replicate that for others. Check it.

Comment: Actually not a retry mechanism if script_1.sh fails then if i rerun the main_script.sh it should run only script_1.sh . For eg script_1.sh fails on 25th and re-running  on 26th in that case script_1.sh will not run and other script_2.sh will also run which would have completed being daily job

Answer (score 0):

Next to the `crontab`, there also is the `at` feature, which gives the possibility to schedule a task. The main difference is that `crontab` is for repeated tasks, while `at` is for single execution.